# vim spell checking - comments only in LaTeX files

Tags: vim, latex, spell-checking, tex

I use gvim to edit LaTex .tex file. I noticed that it checks spelling on the fly only for the commented text. If I have a mistake in a regular text - no underline. If I comment this text with % , the misspell is underlined immediately. What is wrong? Is there any strange option turned on?

Comment: Should questions like these be moved to http://tex.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: in my case I was including the abstract's body from a separate file with `input`. I put the `begin/end` tags to the abstract file and now it works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The latex ft plugin conveniently defines this behaviour.

[SpellChecker : Spell check text including LaTeX documents](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=499)

[Using latexmk, vim spell checking and vim latex-suite](http://www.tjansson.dk/?p=278)

There is an option that appears to come close:

```
:syntax spell [toplevel | notoplevel | default]
```

### Update

Also

```
:he ft-tex-syntax
```

has very useful tidbits, like

```
Don't Want Spell Checking In Comments? ~

Some folks like to include things like source code in comments and so would
prefer that spell checking be disabled in comments in LaTeX files.  To do
this, put the following in your <.vimrc>: >
      let g:tex_comment_nospell= 1
```

You'll have to figure out whether you can use that/extrapolate from there

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I don't think i use any plugin. Also, it worked fine some time ago, just now it behaves strange

Comment: If you're going to play the 'it worked before' game, there will quickly be the point at which you're simply gonna have to find out what changed yourself. Otherwise, have a look at these resources, or the additional one I'll add in a second

Comment: +1. `let g:tex_comment_nospell=1` works for me with vim 7.3. Works with comments using `%` (as the OP requested), but doesn't work with the `comment` environment. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9303/in-vim-how-to-enable-spellchecking-of-text-only-and-exclude-listings seems to cover the latter.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem (VIM 7.3), but [this post at the vim-latex-devel mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/vim-latex-devel@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00580.html) provided the clue. To get the spell checking working, I had to put

```
syntax spell toplevel
```

in my `~/.vimrc`, but **it has to be declared after**

```
syntax enable
```

or

```
syntax on
```

for it to work.

Comment: Works for me, however spits out a vimrc parsing error at startup, saying toplevel is not a valid option:

```
  Error detected while processing /home/madanh/.vimrc:
  line   74:
  E518: Unknown option: toplevel
```

Comment: Ok, it works even if I just append `syntax spell` to my .vimrc. Now without error.

Comment: Works for me in Vim 7.4.

Answer (score 5):

I don't whether this is a crude hack and the intended solution, but I created a file called .vim/after/syntax/tex.vim
containing the single line:

```
syn match texText "\<\w\+\>" contains=@Spell
```

Now vim spell checks the normal text between the commands and the text passed as parameters, because you cannot differentiate them syntacticly:

```
\frametitle{TextToBeChecked}
\pgfuseimage{VariableNotToBeChecked}
```

Hence, it checks way too much in my preamble. But I have it located in another file, so I don't really care.

Answer (score 3):

This problem often occurs when working with files which are included by a master document.

If you are opening a TeX file which will be included and does not contain a section, chapter, `\begin{document}`, ... you can mark it by adding `%begin-include` at the top of the file. This way vim recognizes the file content as being part of the `texDocZone` region, which enables spellchecking.

With `%end-include` you can set the end of the `texDocZone`.

This behavior seems not to be documented, but is described in the vim syntax file: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/tex.vim

**tl;dr**: Add `%begin-include` to the top of your tex file.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem -- the .tex file for the first chapter of my book spell checked normally, but the file for the second chapter would only spell check the comments.  This apparently happens because vim isn't looking at enough lines of context and gets confused.  Ingo Karkat's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23357364/1682042) fixed it for me.  Specifically, I used:

```
syn sync maxlines=2000
syn sync minlines=500
```

in ~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim

Answer (score 0):

**tldr; don't put `\section` commands in your master `.tex` document**

I made the same observation and I also would insist on "before, it worked and I didn't change anything".

Then I observed that this unwanted behaviour only occurred in `.tex` documents where I have a `master.tex` that *includes* chapters as separate `chapterx.tex` files. Moreover, everything works fine if all the `\section` definitions are in the `chapterx.tex`'s and **NOT** in the `master.tex`.

Otherwise, as I think, the *vim* syntax and spell checking routines have a hard time determining in which region they are, cf. this question [Vim spellcheck not always working in .tex file. Check region in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353009/vim-spellcheck-not-always-working-in-tex-file-check-region-in-vim?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem, but a different solution to it. In some .tex files the spell-check was working as expected others not (documentclass{scrlttr2}). Only in the comments words were underlined ... So I compared the headers of one working and one not working .tex document. I found a surprisingly texblock, which were hindering the spell check in the document itself:

```
\usepackage{array}
\newenvironment{Conditio}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
  {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}
```

And this code was only an "hangover" of a different juridical text, I edited before. Commenting it out, set the normal spell-check with high-lighted texts in the letter document. (MacVim 8.1 latex-suite macOS 10.13.6 vim-latex v1.10.0)

Comment: That's funny. I have had this problem again, but forgot this answer I gave some months ago. And suddenly I realise, that this answer (working!) is from myself! In the upper comment is an embarrassing English mistake: wanted to say "leftover" not a hangover ...

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here worked for me, but I could see if I typed `syntax spell` as a command in vim it would work.

It turns out it was because syntax wasn't being set for the tex filetype automatically, and I found the solution [here](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=3808).

> #### vim only spell checking in TeX comments
>
> Editing a LaTeX document with vim, I noticed it was only spell-checking comments. I fixed this
>   by add this to my `./vimrc`:
>
> `autocmd FileType plaintex,tex,latex syntax spell toplevel`