# Vim spellcheck not always working in .tex file. Check region in Vim

Tags: vim, latex, spell-checking, region

I use Vim to write my `.tex` files, but I am having trouble with the spell checker in Vim.  Sometimes it does not check the words, and I think that it might be for the following reason.

Since Vim is clearly not supposed to check all of the words in the `.tex` document, for example, not the preamble, it only check spelling in certain regions (in the syntax sense).  As I have gathered from [here](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Spellchecker-doesn-t-work-in-all-latex-files-td5718129.html), one of these regions is `texSectionZone`.  These regions can become quite large, indeed a section often is, so Vim is having trouble realising that it actually is in a `texSectionZone` region (or in ay other), and therefore does not check the spelling.  This can happen if I make a search in the document, or any kind of jump that skips multiple lines (or rather pages).

The way that I concluded this might be the reason is the following:  I know that the command

```
:echo synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),1),"name")
```

prints the name of the region/regions you are in (I found it [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Identify_the_syntax_highlighting_group_used_at_the_cursor)), so when the spell checker did not work I tried this, and it told me that it was not in any region at all.  The places it did work, I was in a region where it ought to check the spelling.

So far my only solution is to find the nearest section above the point I want the speller to check, and then manually move the cursor back down to the given point.

Ideally I would very much like a solution that ensures that this does not happen, but I would also settle for a way to manually make vim 'update' which region it is in, without me having to move the cursor a lot.  In the latter case I am thinking of a solution which could be made to a shortcut.

PS  I was in doubt about what to call the question.  If you come up with a title which explain the problem better, fell free to change it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`syntax/tex.vim` already uses quite elaborate *sync patterns* to ensure that the syntax highlighting is accurate, but for long and complex documents, this may still fail.

Best you can do is trying to increase both values of

```
syn sync maxlines=200
syn sync minlines=50
```

(e.g. to 2000 and 500). Put this in `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim` to override the defaults.

```
syntax sync fromstart
```

might give the best results, but may be too slow. You'll find a description of syntax syncing at `:help :syn-sync`.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.  I tried to read in `:help sync-syn`, but I must admit that I do not really understand how things work.  How does Vim update the syntax?  Is a choice about this made somewhere.  Maybe this is confusing.  What I'm asking is probably: if I run `syntax sync fromstart` does it then update the syntax from the beginning of the document _once_, or does it tell Vim that it should always do syntax syncronizing from the beginning?

Comment: The latter one; if this doesn't slow down Vim too much, stick to it!

Comment: Okay.  Most of the places on the net, where people suggest it, they make it sound as it is only once.  If I run `:syn sync maxlines=200` and `:syn sync minlines=50` afterwards, do I then set it back to normal (as default)?

Comment: This needs to be set only once, best in the _after_ directory mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 62):

Spell checking is not done where no syntax group are defined (or found by vim). I find it useful to enable spell checking even for the undefined group (see *toplevel* in vim's syntax documentation).

To do so, write the command:

```
syntax spell toplevel
```

in the file `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim`. Make the file if it does not exist.

Comment: Maybe obvious but it had me stumped; gotta use `set spell` before this will work.

Comment: I didn't have a problem with tex files but did with yacc; thanks for this! BTW: you of course don't need this in a special file. You can have it in your `.vimrc` file as well after the setting of the spell option (as @Justapigeon mentioned). Whether doing it in `.vimrc` causes any other issues or is not the best way I do not know but for me it works fine - at least at first glance. Ah but it might be annoying in files that I don't want spellcheck in. Thanks for the tips anyway!

Comment: I added the line `autocmd FileType tex syntax spell toplevel` to my `.vimrc` and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I manually set filetype `:set filetype=plaintex` and then vim spell works very well for my .tex documents, which are LaTeX files.  many of my .tex files are automatically recognized as ***filetype=tex***  and when that happens, vim's *spell* will not check the spelling of a single word, even though most of the text are English sentences, frequently whole paragraphs, without any LaTeX syntax at all.  I've also found that I can set filetype `:set filetype=latex` and that also works, but some of my custom commands `\dosomething` are not recognized as syntax, and they don't get a special font color... so I manually `:set filetype=plaintex` and at least I get the font color for my custom LaTeX commands in a special font color.